# Open terminal window and execute Python script on startup

Tags: 12.04, startup-applications, python3

I have a Python script which I would like to execute at every startup.
I can run it by adding this to the startup applications:

```
python3 /path/to/script.py
```

That works, but it doesn't open a terminal window, so I can't see the program's output.
How could I make it open a terminal window and execute the script in there?

Note: I get the window to stay open with `input(' ')` at the end of the Python script.
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This one should work:

```
gnome-terminal -e "python3 /path/to/script.py"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works perfectly. Just out of interest - do you have any idea how you would do something similar on Windows7?

Comment: Try *start cmd /k python3 X:\path\to\script.py*

Answer (score 3):

To run an application in a system's default terminal we may define a `.desktop` file we can then add to our startup applications in `~/.config/autostart` with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Name of Application
Exec=python3 path/to/application.py
Terminal=true
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
NoDisplay=true
```

Note that the terminal will close on termination of our script only if our terminal profile is set to do so (default in gnome-terminal but editable from profile settings).