# Run /home/martyn/Desktop/Scanned Items$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer & in /etc/rc.local

Tags: 16.04, scripts

I want to Run

```
/home/martyn/Desktop/Scanned Items$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer &
```

in

```
/etc/rc.local
```

When I try & do this I get

```
sh /etc/rc.local: 13: /etc/rc.local: /home/martyn/Desktop/Scanned: not found
```

Comment: It also looks like you'd be better of running the program on log-in inside a user session instead of on start-up as root user. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/351582/open-terminal-window-and-execute-python-script-on-startup.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to escape white-space characters. So instead of:

```
/home/martyn/Desktop/Scanned Items
```

Use this:

```
/home/martyn/Desktop/Scanned\ Items
```

*edit*: David Foerster has a good point about not running this as root.

Comment: I have renamed the folder on the desktop to Scanned,will this escape white-space characters?                                                                                                          I now get /etc/rc.local: 13: /etc/rc.local: /Desktop/Scanned: not found

Comment: The backslash escapes the space after it. This way the shell knows that what follows is not another argument, but a part of the path.

Comment: I don't see that white spaces have anything to do with my problem now. I have set up a samba share instead.